# Run Ruby script on Docker

Tags: ruby, selenium, docker

I am trying to run a Ruby script I have made that uses Selenium on Docker. I am guessing it's because I need to also install Firefox somehow, although I thought that this was included in the Selenium gem. As "It works on my machine" I'm a bit lost how to make it work on a Docker instance.

My Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM ruby:2.3-onbuild

COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
COPY . .

RUN bundle install

ENTRYPOINT ["ruby", "runner.rb"]
```

Comment: Could you provide more details on what your script (`runner.rb` I presume) do? Also, what errors are you seeing when you try to run it?

Comment: @phss yes, sorry I should have done that. `runner/rb` simply uses Selenium to do website automation. It uses a chromedriver which I have locally in the project. The error is this one.

`unable to connect to chromedriver http://127.0.0.1:9515 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)`

Answer (score 0):

The firefox browser itself is not included in selenium. Firefox (or any browser) needs to be installed on the machine (docker image) before you can test against it with selenium.

Also keep in mind that if you're using Firefox version 48+ you also need to make sure geckodriver is available on the machine.

In your question you said Firefox but in your comment you said chromedriver. These 2 are not compatible with each other. Also, chromedriver needs to be on the docker image and not locally (if you're using remote).

Are you using an official selenium docker image?